# How to toggle content of a table cell when clicking on link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table with some data in it. Data in 2 columns is just one or two words, but the third column contains around 1000 caracters, I want that one column's data to toggle when clicked on a link.
Here is the code I tried:
HTML

```
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Pretrazi pesme</h2> </br>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Zanr: <input type="text" name="zanr" id="idZanrInput" placeholder="Zanr pesme" onkeyup="sugestija(document.getElementById('idZanrInput').value)">
            <div  id="nazivZanraDiv"></div>
            <br/>
            Postojeci zanrovi: "Pop", "Rock", "House", "Metal" i "Hip-hop".
            </br><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="unos" value="OK">
        </form>

        Niste uneli prihvatljiv zanr, pa prikazujemo sve pesme iz baze.                     <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Naziv</b></td>
                                <td><b>Izvodjac</b></td>
                                <td><b>Tekst</b></td>                               
                                <td><b>Zanr</b></td>
                            </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Simple boy</td>
                                <td>Karnivool</td>
                                <td ><p id="tekst">I'm high above the world
Why should I feel pain
Or feel alone
To be protected like a simple boy
If I choose to let you down
Begin to know

You're free to go
You're free to go

I will fight until there's nothing left
Cross the world together from this sinking ship
Or drown alone
Off the coast
Facing nothingness
Drawn to feel the emptiness
Oh help me now
Describe the scene

You're free to go
(We'll face these things some other day)
You're free to go
(I won't leave you you're not ok)
You're free to go 
(We'll face these things some other day)
You're free to go
(I won't leave you you're not ok)

Simple boy, stay here
Simple boy, don't wander
Simple boy, you're safe here
Simple boy, simple boy

So when did we lose the plot
Were running against the clock
Don't hesitate
Or you will never know

Simple boy, you're free to go
Don't wander, you're free to go
Simple boy, you're free to go
You're safe here, you're free to go
You're free to go
You're free t</p><a href="#" onclick="toggle(display)"; id="zagrade">[...]</a></td>                                                         
                                <td>metal</td>
```

CSS:

```
#tekst{
  height:60px;
  line-height:15px; /* Height / no. of lines to display */
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle(#tekst) {
    var state = document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display;
    if (state == 'hidden') {
        document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Instead of display I tried using overflow, writing some scripts, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: make your code without php, and add your js

Comment: I have to use php it's for my homework

Comment: what is in `toggle(display)`?

Comment: we just need to see your problem, not whole code

Comment: Just to clarify as i'm not entirely sure what you're asking.. You've got an anchor tag. Which when clicked. You want to toggle the display of the third table cell? Yes?

Comment: @user3095317 no homework requests are entertained. Before that Alesha asked you to show us the rendered HTML if you want us to help you!

Comment: oh sorry, didn't get what you wanted, don't know how I forgot JS, here it is:  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(#tekst) {
     var state = document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display;
      if (state == 'hidden') {
       document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display = 'block';
      } else {
       document.getElementById(#tekst).style.display = 'none';
      }
     }
</script>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and then add it. Don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've created a simple fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/80yrytnt/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="test">Click me</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text..</td>
        <td>Some more text..</td>
        <td>Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text 
            Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text 
            Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text 
            Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table { border:1px solid #000; }
td { border-right:1px solid #000; }
td:last-child { border-right:none; }
td.hideMe { display:none; }
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('td:last-child').toggleClass('hideMe');
});
```

I don't know how your page is layed out. But this is working solution. You need to use jQuery's `toggleClass` **OR** `toggle` to hide and unhide the given element. I've used a `last-child` selector in my example. You may have an ID or specific class to call instead. But I assume you can edit the code accordingly.

Comment: Yes that's working, but the thing is, I don't want all the text to be hidden, there is a fixed part that will be visible all the time, and a part that's hidden with overflow in css, and that part I want to toggle, sorry for not making it that clear in the first place.

Comment: @user3095317 Can you wrap the text you don't want to show in a `span` and just call the `toggleClass` on that?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm importing data from a database using php, maybe  I could make a column where you can insert extract from text that will be, let's say 200 caracters long, and one more where you insert the whole text,and than toggle between those two, but I hoped there is some solution where it won't depend from a user's input. Hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have a lot of issues in your JavaScript.

1. You cannot use `#tekst` as a parameter.
2. Replace the `#tekst` to `tekst`.
3. Pass `this` instead of anything else.
4. Use ternary operators instead of simple `if` and `else`.
5. There's no `hidden`.

Here's your code:

```
function toggle(tekst) {
    var state = tekst.style.display;
    if (state == 'hidden') {
        tekst.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        tekst.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Instead of the above one, use this:

```
function toggle(tekst) {
    tekst.style.display = (tekst.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```
<td ><p id="tekst"><?php echo $red->tekst?></p><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)";>[...]</a></td>
```

Only if you post your full HTML, we can help you out fully. The meaning of full HTML is, once you have done it using PHP, you may need to View Source of the rendered page and copy the relevant code from there.